# Nautilus freezes when connecting to SSH server

Tags: nautilus, ssh, freeze

I have several nautilus bookmarks pointing to SSH servers, so that I can easily access them. Out of nowhere this doesn't work anymore. When I open a bookmark or enter `ssh://user@server` in the location bar, Nautilus completely freezes and doesn't recover (edit: same with sftp://). I can kill Nautilus and the desktop will load again. Everything else works as it should. As soon as I try to access a server through ssh, nautilus freezes again.

Nothing was changed on the servers and no updates have been installed on the computer. A reboot doesn't help, either.

I use key-authentication if that is important. I AM being asked for the key-passphrase and then the freeze occurs.

Update: This stopped working while I was using it. I was uploading some files, did something else, and when I got back to upload some more edited files the freezing began. To me this feels like some messed up or incomplete cache files that nautilus still tries to use.

Comment: You should file a bug report, check the following instructions: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Comment: have you checked from the CLI to make sure your keys aren't expired/there isn't some uncaught command line prompt?  always a fan of pinning down a problem before i say "something is wrong".  that way I can say "I think THIS is wrong"

Comment: CLI works. On other computers with the same configuration Nautilus server-connections still work. See updates to the question.

Comment: If you open nautilus from a shell and try to click on a ssh bookmark, are there any errors reported on the cli?

Comment: Unfortunately nautilus automatically detaches itself when run from the CLI, so you won't get any messages. There are no verbosity-options, either.

Comment: dmesg gives me two segfaults, if that helps:

[271440.261858] nautilus[19330]: segfault at 20 ip 00649ddf sp bfdd9c20 error 4 in libgobject-2.0.so.0.2600.0[61d000+40000]

[271442.005275] indicator-appli[2021]: segfault at 6b736564 ip 0804b8bc sp bfea6810 error 4 in indicator-application-service[8048000+7000]

Comment: did you figure out how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

It may not be a perfect solution but sometimes it may work.

Just try `sftp://user@server` instead of `ssh://user@server`

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think they are synonymous. Anyway, the result is the same ;(

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried mounting the remote filesystem via sshfs and then browsing it via Nautilus?
I think that if that works it would then eliminate the remote server, the local ssh client, and non-gvfs parts of Nautilus as problems. (I'm not sure what is in the middle there or if gvfs is involved at all- but it would provide more information if this works.)

Comment: Using sshfs works. Opening the mounts with nautilus works as expected. If it wouldn't work it'd mean nautilus can't open fuse mounts anymore. I tried deleting .gvfs but that didn't help. I'll now try to force-remove/purge all nautilus and gvfs-related packages and reinstall them.